# Как добавить дата-атрибут к элементу?

Tags: javascript

```js
$('.date_extradition').data('rule', 'test');
```

ожидалось что получу `data-rule-test`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно немного по другому

```js
$('.root').attr('data-rule-test', 'test');
console.log($('.root').data())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='root'>data-rule-test</div>
```